# How many exceptional conductors are there?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

We say that a conductor $q$ is exceptional if there is a primitive quadratic character $\chi$ modulo $q$ such that $L(s,\chi)$ has a real zero $\beta$ such that $\beta > 1-c/\log q$ (where $c$ is some tiny absolute constant).

We know from a result of Landau that if there is a sequence of such $q$, say $(q_i)$, then $q_{i+1}> q_i^C$ for some $C$ (another absolute constant).

It follows that the number of exceptional conductors $q$ in $[1,N]$ is $O(\log\log N)$.

> Is any better (unconditional) upper bound than this known, on the number of exceptional conductors in the interval $[1,N]$?

It is, of course, conjectured that there are no exceptional conductors at all.

Comment: Landau's result is actually only stated for the imaginary quadratic case (in terms of the class number). http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002505142

Comment: I think this is the state of the art.

Comment: @GregMartin It wouldn't surprise me. But there's a lot of interesting results on exceptional zero repulsion etc, and I was hoping that maybe one of these could be leveraged to do a little better for my question. (which asks for less than bounding the gap between exceptional conductors, for example). I don't have a good intuition though for what is possible Vs impossible in this area.